Reuse buffer after sending it using channel
I just want to resue buffer or avoid using buffer.to_owned() after it be send by channel, becasue buffer.to_owned()  is expensive when iterated tens of thousands of times.
Here is the simplified code:
use crossbeam_channel::bounded;
use std::thread;

fn main() {

    thread::scope(|work| {
        let batch_size = 100000000;
        let (in_s, in_r) = bounded(1);
        work.spawn(move || {
            let mut buffer = Vec::with_capacity(batch_size);
            for i in 0..10000{
                buffer.extend(std::iter::repeat(4).take(batch_size));//read data from file
                in_s.send(buffer.to_owned()).unwrap();
                buffer.clear();
            }
        });

        work.spawn(move || {
            while let Ok(data) = in_r.recv() {
                // do some caculation
            }
        });
    });
}

So how can I modify the above code to reuse the buffer or avoid using buffer.to_owned()?
I have tried to resend buffer in the receiving thread to the sending thread, but failed.

Re-use it where? In the sending thread its already re-used between the iterations over the variable i. There's no way to not clone the buffer before putting it into the channel, except to not try to re-use the buffer between iterations.

I mean don't clone the buffer. For example, use two fixed buffers and always keep one for reading and one for writing.

You can't do it with a single buffer since the receiving thread needs to be able to use the buffer at the same time as the sending thread. You can do it if you use two buffers, and two channels so that each task can send the buffer to the other task when it's finished using it:
use crossbeam_channel::bounded;
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    thread::scope(|work| {
        let batch_size = 100000000;
        // A channel to send input buffers from the reading task
        // to the processing task
        let (input_s, input_r) = bounded(1);
        // A channel to send empty buffers from the processing task
        // to the reading task
        let (empty_s, empty_r) = bounded(1);

        work.spawn(move || {
            for i in 0..10000 {
                let mut buffer: Vec::<_> = empty_r.recv().unwrap();
                buffer.clear();
                buffer.extend(std::iter::repeat(4).take(batch_size));//read data from file
                input_s.send(buffer).unwrap();
            }
        });
        // Allocate two buffers and send them to the reader task
        empty_s.send (Vec::with_capacity(batch_size)).unwrap();
        empty_s.send (Vec::with_capacity(batch_size)).unwrap();

        work.spawn(move || {
            while let Ok(data) = input_r.recv() {
                // do some caculation

                // Send the empty buffer back
                empty_s.send (data).unwrap();
            }
        });
    });
}

Playground

Rust won't let you do that (without unsafe code) because there's a chance that the receiving thread would still be reading the buffer while your start modifying it.
One way you can work around that is to share a buffer through an Arc, and only overwrite the one in the sender thread if the receiving thread has droppped its reference.
Note that this is only useful if one of the two threads does something other than write or read to the buffer,
use crossbeam_channel::bounded;
use std::{sync::Arc, thread};

fn main() {

    thread::scope(|work| {
        let batch_size = 100000000;
        let (in_s, in_r) = bounded(1);
        work.spawn(move || {
            let mut shared_buffer = Arc::new(Vec::with_capacity(batch_size));
            for _ in 0..10000{
                # Try to reuse the buffer if this is the only reference to it
                # otherwise use a new one
                let buffer = if let Some(buffer) = Arc::get_mut(&mut shared_buffer) {
                    buffer.clear();
                    buffer
                } else {
                    shared_buffer = Arc::new(Vec::with_capacity(batch_size));
                    Arc::get_mut(&mut shared_buffer).unwrap()
                };

                buffer.extend(std::iter::repeat(4).take(batch_size));//read data from file
                in_s.send(shared_buffer.clone()).unwrap();
            }
        });

        work.spawn(move || {
            while let Ok(data) = in_r.recv() {
                // do some caculation
            }
        });
    });
}

By the way, buffer.to_owned() is actually a clone() in disguise, because buffer is already an Owned Vec<> type, so to_owned is actually called on the inner array.
